# adding cygwin bin directory to powershell path environment variable ... cygwin within powershell

Tags: powershell, cygwin

Powershell is great for scripting. But when it comes to everyday use, certain things can be a huge PITA!!

so i thought it would be great if i could do something like this in my profile.ps1:

```
$env:path = "$($env:path);c:\cygwin\bin"
```

to get access to utilities like tar, zip, etc... but this doesn't work. The variable looks right when i do:

```
PS > $env:path
```

but when i try to do, say,

```
PS > unzip foo.zip
```

i get a command not found type error.

WTF PowerShell!?

> edit: great answers! I looked at it with fresh eyes this morning and realized that I just needed to spell 'cygwin' correctly! now I don't have to switch back and forth between two consoles. It should be noted for anyone who uses this tip that your path in powershell is evaluated in order - if you put c:\cygwin\bin at the end of the $env:path variable, it will be searched last, so it won't interfere with existing powershell aliases / cmdlets.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me:

To set your profile:

```
$command = '$env:path = $env:path + ";C:\Program Files\Notepad++"'
$command | Out-File -FilePath $PROFILE -Append -Encoding UTF8
```

Or just the current shell:

```
$env:path = $env:path + ";C:\Program Files\Notepad++"
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `$env:path` to add the cygwin bin to PATH should work as long as you are trying to use it in the same Powershell session. If you open a new console or if you close and open Powershell, it will not be persisted. Otherwise, what you are doing should work. Make sure you are indeed adding the correct path. If you want to persist the changes, add the line to your `$profile`.

Also, try using the Mingw / Msys / Msysgit utils. I find Mingw to be more lightweight than cygwin ( if you are using cygwin just to get some of these utils.)

Answer (score -2):

PowerShell by default is only going to modify its local copy of PATH. When you run an external command, they aren't going to see the local environment variables.

Per this [TechNet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730964.aspx), you can fall back to the .NET static method SetEnvironmentVariable to do this at the user level if you want this to be a permanent change:

```
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("TestVariable", "Test value.", "User")
```

Comment: while `$env:path` is process level, it should still work for what OP is trying to do. Using Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable just sets it at user level.

Comment: Ah, true. I didn't notice that he was making a call based on environment variable, rather than assuming the external process requiring it.